# how to call my button component in my app-root component in "row-fluid div"

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have created a simple application in Angular8, and using some routing link and components.

on click on left Navigation I want call that component in my middle of the body as per attached screen shot.

My workings for:

```
**app-routing.module.ts**
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ButtonComponent } from './button/button.component';
import { CardsComponent } from './cards/cards.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'button', component: ButtonComponent},
  {path: 'cards', component: CardsComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/button', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path: '**', component:PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I have written all my HTML code in **app.compnent.html**

```
**app.compnent.html**
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button/button.component';
import { CardsComponent } from './cards/cards.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ButtonComponent,
    CardsComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: show some working demo

Comment: Use Sub/Pub architecture to orchestrate the communication... Provide the a service in the app module. This service publishes click events from source (Left Navigation in your case) to zero or many targets (Central Panel in your case). Therefore, you will inject this service in both Left Navigation Component and in Central Panel Component. --- Let me know if it works!

Comment: Even better, you can use @ngrx/effects

Comment: I tried.. but not chieving the result .. if any 1 have working demo, please share codpen, jsfiddle